# Invalid Token Java Post Get/Post Request

Tags: java, json, rest, access-token, httpurlconnection

I am new to Rest API based on Java. The purpose is to obtain an access token from a particular API Token URL by sending a POST request. However, upon running the following program, the access token cannot be used (invalid token) after executing the Post and Get requests.

I would like to know if there is anything I would need to improve. Note that the requirements to retrieve the JSON data include the following info such as the url, the client_id and the grant_type.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        useBearerToken(getAUthToken());
    }

    private static String getAUthToken() throws IOException {
        String URL = "http://api/service/get_token";
        URL obj = new URL(URL);
        String auth = "something";
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeaderValue);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        final String POST_PARAMS = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=something";

        // Start: For POST only
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        // End: For POST only
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }

            return get_token(response);

        } else {
            throw new IOException("POST request does not worked");
        }
    }

    private static String get_token(StringBuffer response) {
        String res1 = response.toString();
        String retrieved_token = null;

        Map<String, String> skipDuplicatesMap = Stream.of(res1.split(",")).
                map(el -> el.split(":")).
                collect(toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> arr[1], (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));

        for(String key : skipDuplicatesMap.keySet()) {
            if (key.contains("access_token")) {
                retrieved_token = skipDuplicatesMap.get(key);
            }
        }

        String the_token = retrieved_token.substring(1,retrieved_token.length() - 1);

        return the_token;
    }

    private static void useBearerToken(String access_token) throws IOException {
        // Sending get request
        URL url = new URL("http://api/service/get_records?source=etp&startEntryDate=2022-01-07&endEntryDate=2022-01-22");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        StringBuffer response = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        String authString = "Bearer " + access_token;
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authString);
        //System.out.println(authString);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println(response);

        } else {
            System.out.println("GET request does not worked");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much. If there is anything I am missing, I would be highly appreciated.